# How to fill histogram by different columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, histogram, fill

I got stuck in my project and would be very grateful for the help.
My goal is to explore the relationship between type (A, B, or C) and total income. I want to plot the income in a histogram and fill in the color by type.
My original data looked like this:

| ID | year | income | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 2015 | 300 | A |
| x1 | 2015 | 700 | C |
| x1 | 2016 | 1000 | A |
| x1 | 2016 | 90 | B |
| x1 | 2016 | 100 | B |
| x2 | 2015 | 2000 | A |
| x2 | 2015 | 150 | B |
| x2 | 2015 | 500 | C |
| x2 | 2015 | 45 | C |
| x2 | 2016 | 100 | B |
| x3 | 2015 | 111 | C |

In this case, by plotting the income on the x-axis and using aes(fill = type), the colors fill properly. See the histogram here

[image]

```
h <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=type,x=income))
h+geom_histogram()
```

However, while using the first table the data on the actual personal income for that year is lost, because when I draw a histogram, each line is treated as a different individual. For example, x1 individual income in 2015 is attributed to 300 and 700 bins even though his total income is 1000 on that year. So after summing up the income received and the types used, I get the following table:

| ID | year | income_sum | typeA | typeB | typeC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 2015 | 1000 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| x1 | 2016 | 1190 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| x2 | 2015 | 2695 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| x2 | 2016 | 100 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| x3 | 2015 | 111 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

```
h <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=income_sum))
h+geom_histogram()
```

This time, the histogram can accurately represent total income, but fails to fill in three different colors by type (A, B, C). See the histogram here.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like the following one?

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(ID,year) %>% summarize(income=sum(income), type=unique(type)) %>%
ggplot(aes(fill=type,x=income)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]
Note that after the `group_by` you have the following tibble:

```
   ID    year  income type 
  <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr>
1 x1    2015    1000 A    
2 x1    2015    1000 C    
3 x1    2016    1190 A    
4 x1    2016    1190 B    
5 x2    2015    2695 A    
6 x2    2015    2695 B    
7 x2    2015    2695 C    
8 x2    2016     100 B    
9 x3    2015     111 C
```

**[EDIT]**

If you want the bar heights to be proportionate to the number of times they appear, the following should work:

```
df <- data %>% group_by(ID, year, type) %>% 
               summarise(income=sum(income), count = n()) %>% 
               group_by(ID,year) %>% 
               summarize(income=sum(income), type=type, count=count)
df

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID, year [5]
  ID    year  income type  count
  <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr> <int>
1 x1    2015    1000 A         1
2 x1    2015    1000 C         1
3 x1    2016    1190 A         1
4 x1    2016    1190 B         2
5 x2    2015    2695 A         1
6 x2    2015    2695 B         1
7 x2    2015    2695 C         2
8 x2    2016     100 B         1
9 x3    2015     111 C         1

df %>% ggplot(aes(fill=type, color=type, x=income, y=count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width = 50, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Note that there is one difference. Since the values `100` and `111` are not exactly same (unlike the others), the bars corresponding to `B` and `C` at these values are not stacked on top of one another, rather they are overlapped (one starts at 100 and another at 111).

**[EDIT2]**

We need binning additionally to achieve what you want (change binwidth if needed, currently it's set at 50),

```
bins <- seq(min(df$income), max(df$income), 50)
df$bin <- sapply(df$income, function(x) max(which(bins <= x)))

df <- df %>%  group_by(bin) %>%
  mutate(income = mean(income), bin=bin) 

df

    ID    year  income type  count   bin
    <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int> <int>
  1 x1    2015   1000  A         1    19
  2 x1    2015   1000  C         1    19
  3 x1    2016   1190  A         1    22
  4 x1    2016   1190  B         2    22
  5 x2    2015   2695  A         1    52
  6 x2    2015   2695  B         1    52
  7 x2    2015   2695  C         2    52
  8 x2    2016    106. B         1     1
  9 x3    2015    106. C         1     1

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=type, color=type, x=income, y=count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width = 50)
```

[image]

Note that the income for a bin is set to the average of the datapoints present inside the bin.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a slightly different result - to have just three colors (for typeA, typeB and typeC).

Comment: something like the above one?

Comment: Thank you! Almost! Is it possible to maintain the proportions of the types? For example, x1 chooses type B twice and type A once in 2016. So would it be possible to fill two-thirds with type B color and one-third with type A color?

Comment: How about now, is this something you want?

Comment: Is it possible that the columns do not overlap? Which means that the number of types in each bin is summed and then proportionally filled.  For example, The first bin from the second histogram should be the same as from the first histogram you provided.

Comment: How about now? we can do binning of the income variable to achieve that

Comment: Very well! Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question: is it possible to fill my second graph by type ratio? For example, there is only one person in the last column. So the height of the column should be 1, and it is filled with colors accordingly as in your last graph.